# How can I parse the argument in the situation that I don't know the name, the value and the way they present in golang

Tags: go, parsing, arguments, command-line-interface

I want to collect all the arguments in `golang`, but I will not know the number of them, the name, the value type or the way they present. For example:

`go run main.go --p1 v1 --p2=v2 -p3 --p4 -p5 v5 -p6=v6`

As you see, the param can be assign with the value by `--p1 v1` or `--p2=v2` and can be have one or two `-`, or just need appear (like `-p3` or `--p4`). Note that it can be more than 6 args and no one must have.  And also I dont know they will p1,p2,p3,...

There is a way for me to get all the arguments may appear into a map? In this situation, it will `map[p1:v1 p2:v2 p3:"" p4:"" p5:v5 p6:v6]`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to collect all the arguments in golang

All arguments are already collected by Go in the [`os.Args`](https://pkg.go.dev/os@go1.20.1#Args) variable. How you parse the contents of that depends entirely on your requirements. For example the package [`flag`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag@go1.20.1) is often enough, but that package requires the cli arguments' names to be known and the flags pre-defined before any parsing is done. And since you say you don't know the names you cannot use the `flag` package, instead you should parse the contents of `os.Args` yourself, or look for a 3rd party solution.

---

The following example is a naive approach that *does* produce the desired output but does not handle bad input and whatever other edge case I have not bothered to consider but may occur.

```golang
flags := make(map[string]string)
for i := 1; i < len(os.Args); i++ {
    a := strings.TrimLeft(os.Args[i], "-")

    // arg=val?
    if i := strings.IndexByte(a, '='); i > -1 {
        flags[a[:i]] = a[i+1:]
        continue
    }
    // arg val?
    if len(os.Args) > i+1 && !strings.HasPrefix(os.Args[i+1], "-") {
        flags[a] = os_Args[i+1]
        i++
        continue
    }
    // arg?
    flags[a] = ""
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/eY8oM2CZyCT